# Is it possible to run Swift testcases from command line without an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, swift, command-line

I have made some extensions for Array & String class in Array.swift and String.swift files; I have also added unit test for them, in ArrayTest.swift and StringTest.swift, respectively. Now I would like to run these unit tests from command line **without an Xcode project file**.

After reading [How can I run XCTest for a swift application from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248439/how-can-i-run-xctest-for-a-swift-application-from-the-command-line) I have came up with something like this:

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks \
  -Xlinker -rpath \
  -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks \
  -lswiftCore Array.swift \
  -module-name array_extension
```

... which seems to compiling the array extensions into a module. But how can I compile / link the `ArrayTest.swift` file against this module?

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/scan

Comment: Set up a package, including a test target, then you can just run `swift test`