# Add xctest dependency to Xcode 7 project

Tags: xcode, macos, xctest

Created a new OS X library project, deleted the Objective-C stubs and add a Swift file (Empty.swift).  In the same directory, added a unit test (new->Unit Test), EmptyTest.swift.  The code generated won't compile because this OS X library project doesn't know how to resolve the dependency to XCTest.

XCTest is at this location /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/XCTest

The solution for command line tools is here ([How can I run XCTest for a swift application from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248439/how-can-i-run-xctest-for-a-swift-application-from-the-command-line)).  How to add the dependency using Xcode 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Unit test case via new target instead of creating file in the same target

```
File - New - Target - OS X -Test - OS X Unit Testing Bundle
```

When you create new unit testing bundle it creates new unit test swift file with XCTest as dependancy 
When you run this target it don't show the error of XCTest

**Update** : If you want it in the same target.
In the Build Settings find `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` and add `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` in it 
after that if you build your app will build successfully

Comment: This your workflow is a good solution if I don't care to have my unit test alongside the code it's testing. But I'd like to mingle them and learn how to resolve dependencies like this.

Answer (score 0):

Show the File Inspector and check the Target Membership on EmptyTest.swift. I'm betting you added it to the production target, when it should be in the test target instead.